# w2ui Toolbar items- is there a way to add custom icons by URL?

Tags: javascript, css, w2ui

In w2ui toolbars items, when you create then, you can specify the css class for your icon.Like in the example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var btnCount = 0;
    $('#toolbar').w2toolbar({
        name: 'toolbar',
        items: [
            { type: 'button', id: 'append', text: 'Append', icon: 'w2ui-icon-plus' },
            { type: 'button', id: 'insert', text: 'Insert', icon: 'w2ui-icon-cross' }
        ],
        onClick: 
            //Some Code
});</script>
```

Where 'w2ui-icon-plus' and w2ui-icon-cross' are CSS  classes.

However, that means you must have a CSS Class defined for that icon. How can i set the icon just by the imagem URL?

Since i can have dynamics images, i cant create a CSS Class for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not possible.

Your best bet would be to identify the toolbar button you want to manipulate with JQuery and change the background picture.

Here's an example that changes the background image of the first button:

```
$(".w2ui-tb-image").first().css({
    "background-image": "url(http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-16-16-1.jpg)"
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6wkunhz7/

Fiddle base code taken from here: http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!toolbar/toolbar-1

You may need to adapt the CSS some more, to make everything look nice, but you should get the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have another method just look here, the code css .icona:before and after add to the icon property of w2ui...Bye

[Add custom icons in 'w2ui' toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092892/add-custom-icons-in-w2ui-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

as your code your can modify or change icon by:

> ```
> mtoolbar = w2ui.grid.toolbar;
> mtoolbar.set("append",{icon: '', img:'icon-append'});
> mtoolbar.set("insert",{icon: '', img:'icon-other'});
> mtoolbar.refresh(); //this line may not be required, please test.
> ```

icon-save and icon-man is css class should be prepared in this format(may be general format for icon class).

> .icon-append{
>       background:url('icons/youricon1.png') no-repeat center center;
>   }
>
> .icon-other{
>   background:url('icons/youricon2.png') no-repeat center center;

Comment: But then you still have to define the image URL statically via CSS.